# Getting NPE error when trying to mock ElasticClient in Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, elasticsearch, junit, mockito

I am new to Mockito framework, and I am working on writing tests for the class containing ElasticClient. Below is my actual method:

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class CreateIndex {

    private final RestHighLevelClient elasticClient;

    @Autowired
    public IndexService(final RestHighLevelClient elasticClient) throws IOException {
        this.elasticClient = elasticClient;
    }

    public boolean createIndex(String id, String index) {
        try {
            IndexRequest request = new IndexRequest(index);
            request.id(id);
            elasticClient.index(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.warn(e.getMessage());
        }
        return false;
    }
```

My test code looks like this:

```
public class TestCreateIndex {
   CreateIndex createIndex;
    @Mock
    RestHighLevelClient elasticClient;
    @Rule
    public MockitoRule rule = MockitoJUnit.rule();
    @Before
    public void before() throws IOException {
        createIndex = new CreateIndex(elasticClient);
    }

@Test
    public void TestCreateIndex() throws IOException {
            IndexRequest request = new IndexRequest("1");
            request.id("1");
            Mockito.when(elasticClient.index(request,(RequestOptions.DEFAULT))).thenReturn(indexResponse);

    }
}
```

For the line `Mockito.when(elasticClient.index(request,RequestOptions.DEFAULT )).thenReturn(indexResponse);`(RequestOptions is some Class), I am getting below error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(org.elasticsearch.client.Request)" because "this.client" is null

    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1514)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1484)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequestAndParseEntity(RestHighLevelClient.java:1454)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.index(RestHighLevelClient.java:871)
```

Not sure, how to mock elasticClient properly. Please help.

Comment: Please show us entire stack trace

Comment: @Lesiak I have added the updated stack trace, please see

Comment: Anyone please help me with the NPE error!! :(

Comment: The problem is mockito-specific, not typical NPE, hence the reopen vote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the method you are trying to stub is final:

```
public final IndexResponse index(IndexRequest indexRequest, 
                                 RequestOptions options) throws IOException
```

Mockito does not support mocking final methods out of the box,
instead it calls the real method, which causes NPE, since `private final RestClient client;` is not initialized.

Fortunately, stubbing final methods can be easily added as a configuration option.
See [Mock Final Classes and Methods with Mockito](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-final)

> Before Mockito can be used for mocking final classes and methods, it needs to be configured.
>
> We need to add a text file to the project's src/test/resources/mockito-extensions directory named org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker and add a single line of text:
>
> `mock-maker-inline`
>
> Mockito checks the extensions directory for configuration files when it is loaded. This file enables the mocking of final methods and classes.

Alternatively, since mockito 2.7.6, you can use `mockito-inline` artifact (instead of `mockito-core`) that enables inline mock making

Comment: I checked my IndexRequest.class and IndexResponse.class, none of them are final classes. But yeah, I do have RestClient as private final `private final RestClient client;`

Comment: The mockito version used in my code is 2.23.4. So mockito-inline is not supported and also `mock-maker-inline` thing is causing a lot of errors because of the version issues between java and mockito.

Comment: 23 is greater than 7 isn't it? Also, I said the method is final, not it's arguments. RestClient is a field in RestHighLevelClient, not in your code. Please take time to re-read my answer.